# mybatis is not initialized in case of ejb.jar

Tags: java, cdi, mybatis, ear

It seems what I am doing is not complete and something is still missing from my code.

I would like to use MyBatis + mybatis-cdi within an EJB. My jar contains only one stateless ejb class and a session factory producer class. I think that the problem is that my MyBatis Session Factory Producer is never called by EE container (I can not see the "`MyBatis SessionFactory is initializing...`" log entry in the log file).

The following error appears during deployment time:

```
WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ConfigurationDao with qualifiers @Default at injection point ....
```

When I pack the same classes (EJB + session factory producer classes) to war then I can see in the log that session factory producer is called. But I need to pack them to a simple ejb instead of war because I am building an EJB service which is used by another wars.

This is my assembly structure:

```
EAR
  +--- commons.jar (interfaces)
  +--- configuration-service.jar (stateless ejb + mybatis mapper interface + session factory producer)
  +--- restapi-1.war
  +--- restapi-2.war
```

**The following classes sit in configuration-service.jar:**

Session Factory Producer

```
//@Stateless
public class SessionFactoryProducer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = ...;

    @ApplicationScoped
    @Produces
    @SessionFactoryProvider
    public SqlSessionFactory produce() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("MyBatis SessionFactory is initializing...");

        try (Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("mybatis.xml")) {
            return new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Stateless ejb

```
@Stateless
public class ConfigurationBean implements ConfigurationService {

   @Inject
   private ConfigurationDao configurationDao;

   public void setStringValue(final Configuration configuration) {
      ...
      // save to database
      configurationDao.insert(configuration);
      ...
   }

   public String getStringValue(final String key) {
      return configurationDao.findByKey(key).map(Configuration::getValue).orElse(null);
   }
}
```

MyBatis mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface ConfigurationDao {

    @Select("SELECT ...")
    Configuration findByKey(@Param("key") String key);

    @Insert("INSERT INTO ...")
    void insert(Configuration configuration);
}
```

**Usage from war (jersey rest)**

```
@Path("/")
public class MyClass {
    @Inject
    private ConfigurationService configurationService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_UTF8_JSON)
    public String doSomething() {
        String something = configurationService.getStringValue(KEY);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The error actually states you are trying to inject `ConfigurationDAO` **somewhere**. Your question should contain primarily information on **where do you inject it** and where in the EAR deployment structure is the place you inject it into. Is it the injection point inside 'ConfigurationBean' ? If so, do you have `beans.xml` inside your EJB jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my ear/ejb app, here is how I declared my *SessionFactoryProvider*:

```
@Local(ISqlSessionFactoryProvider.class)
@Stateless
public class SqlSessionFactoryProvider implements ISqlSessionFactoryProvider


@Local
public interface ISqlSessionFactoryProvider {

    SqlSessionFactory produceFactory() throws IOException;

}
```

Then in EJBs I do inject *SqlSession* and retrieve *Mapper* from it. But injecting directly mappers should work as specified in the [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/cdi/injection.html).

In my other app: a simple webapp, I declare *SessionFactoryProvider* same way you do.

It might not be the best way to do, but its works.

I think the presence of file "empty" beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This file can be an empty text file (0 bytes) -->
<!-- We're declaring the schema to save you time if you do have to configure 
  this in the future -->
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

</beans>
```

in WEB-INF (for webapp) or META-INF (for ejb-jar) directory may allow container server to active/load few things.
I have just [checked](http://www.mybatis.org/cdi/getting-started.html): it **switches CDI on**.

I actually uses it to declare *TransactionInterceptor* that is not supposed to be related.

Comment: I created a new stateless EJB as per your suggestion and I injected this mybatis session factory to my ConfigurationBean and it works fine. The next issue is MyBatis + Container-Managed Transaction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574276/mybatis-cdi-container-managed-transaction