# MyBatis CDI + Container-Managed Transaction

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, mybatis, ear, ibatis

I would like to use mybatis with container-managed transaction in my aplication. I use mybatis 3.4.2 and mybatis-cdi 1.0.0.

My code works but at the moment I open and close sessions manually and I do not know how to inject either `SqlSession` or `Mapper` to my EJB.

It seems that `mybatis-cdi` does not do its job properly in my case.

**That is my deployment structure:**

```
EAR
  +--- commons.jar (interfaces, POJOs)
  +--- ejb.jar (stateless EJBs + MyBatis mapper + session factory)
  +--- web.war (demo servlet which calls EJB)
```

**commons.jar**

```
/a/
/a/b/
/a/b/commons/
/a/b/commons/mybatis/
/a/b/commons/mybatis/SessionFactoryProducer.class
/a/b/commons/api/
/a/b/commons/api/EchoService.class
/a/b/commons/domain/
/a/b/commons/domain/Configuration.class
/META-INF/
/META-INF/beans.xml
```

SessionFactoryProducer.java (simple interface to produce SqlSessionFactory)

```
public interface SessionFactoryProducer {
    SqlSessionFactory produce() throws IOException;
}
```

EchoService.java (EJB interface)

```
public interface EchoService {
    String echo(String str) throws IOException;
}
```

Configuration.java (simple POJO)

```
class with getters/setters
```

beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

    <interceptors>
        <class>org.mybatis.cdi.JtaTransactionInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>

</beans>
```

**ejb.jar**

```
/a/
/a/b/
/a/b/ejb/
/a/b/ejb/EchoServiceBean.class
/a/b/ejb/dao/
/a/b/ejb/dao/ConfigurationDao.class
/a/b/ejb/SessionFactoryProducerImpl.class
/META-INF/
/META-INF/beans.xml
```

EchoServiceBean.java (simple stateless EJB)

```
@Stateless
public class EchoServiceBean implements EchoService {

    //@Inject
    //private SessionFactoryProducer sqlSessionFactoryProducer;

    //@Inject
    //private SqlSession sqlSession;

    @Inject
    private ConfigurationDao configurationDao;

    @Override
    public String echo(String str) throws IOException {
        // SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactoryProducer.produce().openSession();
        // ConfigurationDao configurationDao = sqlSession.getMapper(ConfigurationDao.class);
        Configuration configuration = configurationDao.findByKey("something");
        LOGGER.info(configuration.toString());

        sqlSession.close();
        return new Date() + ": Hello";
    }
}
```

ConfigurationDao.java (simple MyBatis mapper, nothing special here)

```
@Mapper
public interface ConfigurationDao {
    @Select("SELECT id, key_name, key_value, description "
            + "FROM application.configuration "
            + "WHERE key_name = #{key}")
    Configuration findByKey(@Param("key") String key);
}
```

SessionFactoryProducerImpl.java (EJB, produces MyBatis SqlSessionFactory):

```
@Stateless
public class SessionFactoryProducerImpl implements SessionFactoryProducer {
    @Override
    public SqlSessionFactory produce() throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("MyBatis SessionFactory is initializing...");

        try (Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("mybatis.xml")) {
            SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
            LOGGER.info("Session factory has been obtained");
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }
}
```

beans.xml

```
same then before
```

When I use my `SessionFactoryProducerImpl` EJB to get MyBatis session then everything works fine, but I would like to let manage SqlSession by EE container (open/close/commit/rollback).

The issue appeared after I modified my `SessionFactoryProducerImpl` as per suggestion of the official doc http://www.mybatis.org/cdi/injection.html (remove @Stateless and interface reference, add @Produces, @ApplicationScoped, @SessionFactoryProvider annotations) and after that

1. I inject `org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession` instead of my `SessionFactoryProducerImpl` I get an `Unsatisfied dependencies for type SqlSession with qualifiers @Default` during deploy EAR to server
2. I inject MyBatis mapper which is the `ConfigurationDao` in my case then I get a `There are no SqlSessionFactory producers properly configured` error.

What is the proper way to let EE container to manage MyBatis session?

---

**UPDATE-1**

I tried to inject SqlSessionFactory by name:

```
//@Stateless
public class SessionFactoryProducerImpl /*implements SessionFactoryProducer*/ {
    //@Override
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Produces
    @Named("fooManager")
    @SessionFactoryProvider
    public SqlSessionFactory produce() throws IOException {
       ...
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Stateless
public class EchoServiceBean implements EchoService {
    @Inject @Named("fooManager") ConfigurationDao configurationDao;
    ...
}
```

Log from app server:

```
[Payara 4.1] [INFO] [org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisExtension] [tid: _ThreadID=803 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(40)] [timeMillis: 1492972172749] [levelValue: 800] [[
  MyBatis CDI Module - Found class with @Mapper-annotation: ConfigurationDao]]

[Payara 4.1] [INFO] [org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisExtension] [tid: _ThreadID=803 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(40)] [timeMillis: 1492972172943] [levelValue: 800] [[
  MyBatis CDI Module - SqlSessionFactory producer SessionFactoryProducerImpl.produce]]

[Payara 4.1] [INFO] [org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisExtension] [tid: _ThreadID=803 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(40)] [timeMillis: 1492972172982] [levelValue: 800] [[
  MyBatis CDI Module - Activated]]

[Payara 4.1] [INFO] [org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisExtension] [tid: _ThreadID=803 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(40)] [timeMillis: 1492972172983] [levelValue: 800] [[
  MyBatis CDI Module - Found a bean, which needs a Mapper interface a.b.ejb.dao.ConfigurationDao]]

[Payara 4.1] [INFO] [org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisExtension] [tid: _ThreadID=803 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(40)] [timeMillis: 1492972172984] [levelValue: 800] [[
  MyBatis CDI Module - Managed Mapper dependency: a.b.ejb.dao.ConfigurationDao_fooManager, a.b.ejb.dao.ConfigurationDao]]

[Payara 4.1] [INFO] [org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisExtension] [tid: _ThreadID=803 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(40)] [timeMillis: 1492972172984] [levelValue: 800] [[
  MyBatis CDI Module - Managed SqlSession: org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession_fooManager, org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession]]

[Payara 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=803 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(40)] [timeMillis: 1492972173275] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [ear-packager-1.0#web-1.0.war] at [/web]]]

[Payara 4.1] [INFO] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=803 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(40)] [timeMillis: 1492972173334] [levelValue: 800] [[
  ear-packager-1.0 was successfully deployed in 1,280 milliseconds.]]
```

But I still get exception when I try to use it:

```
Caused by: org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisCdiConfigurationException: There are no SqlSessionFactory producers properly configured.
    at org.mybatis.cdi.CDIUtils.findSqlSessionFactory(CDIUtils.java:55)
    at org.mybatis.cdi.SerializableMapperProxy.getMapper(SerializableMapperProxy.java:57)
    at org.mybatis.cdi.SerializableMapperProxy.<init>(SerializableMapperProxy.java:44)
    at org.mybatis.cdi.MyBatisBean.create(MyBatisBean.java:116)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:744)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:844)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:362)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:373)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector$1.proceed(DefaultInjector.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:173)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.StatelessSessionBeanInjector.inject(StatelessSessionBeanInjector.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.inject(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectEJBInstance(JCDIServiceImpl.java:261)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:488)
    ... 50 more
```

Any idea what is wrong in my code?

---

**UPDATE-2**

Interesting thing. I have just added a new servlet to the war project to display the list of the available beans in CDI container:

```
@WebServlet("/cdi")
public class CdiServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    BeanManager beanManager;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(Object.class, new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() {});

        ...
    }
}
```

I can see that there are 74 beans in my EE container and the most important beans are:

```
(4)
toString(): Extension [class org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisExtension] with qualifiers [@Default]; jar:file:/home/soma/applications/servers/_gombi_/payara-middleware/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/ear-packager-1.0/lib/mybatis-cdi-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension@1[org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisExtension@643ecfa7]
getName(): org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisExtension
getSimpleName(): MybatisExtension
getSuperclass(): class java.lang.Object
getPackage(): org.mybatis.cdi
getAnnotations(): []


(6)
toString(): Managed Bean [class org.mybatis.cdi.CDIUtils$SerializableAnyAnnotationLiteral] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
getName(): org.mybatis.cdi.CDIUtils$SerializableAnyAnnotationLiteral
getSimpleName(): SerializableAnyAnnotationLiteral
getSuperclass(): class javax.enterprise.util.AnnotationLiteral
getPackage(): org.mybatis.cdi
getAnnotations(): []

(8)
toString(): Extension [class org.glassfish.cdi.transaction.TransactionalExtension] with qualifiers [@Default]; bundle://302.0:0/META-INF/services/javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension@1[org.glassfish.cdi.transaction.TransactionalExtension@665874cc]
getName(): org.glassfish.cdi.transaction.TransactionalExtension
getSimpleName(): TransactionalExtension
getSuperclass(): class java.lang.Object
getPackage(): org.glassfish.cdi.transaction
getAnnotations(): []

(18)
toString(): Managed Bean [class org.mybatis.cdi.SqlSessionManagerRegistry] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
getName(): org.mybatis.cdi.SqlSessionManagerRegistry
getSimpleName(): SqlSessionManagerRegistry
getSuperclass(): class java.lang.Object
getPackage(): org.mybatis.cdi
getAnnotations(): [@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped()]

(35)
toString(): Managed Bean [class org.mybatis.cdi.CDIUtils] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
getName(): org.mybatis.cdi.CDIUtils
getSimpleName(): CDIUtils
getSuperclass(): class java.lang.Object
getPackage(): org.mybatis.cdi
getAnnotations(): []

(46)
toString(): Managed Bean [class a.b.commons.domain.Configuration] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
getName(): a.b.commons.domain.Configuration
getSimpleName(): Configuration
getSuperclass(): class java.lang.Object
getPackage(): a.b.commons.domain
getAnnotations(): []

(48)
toString(): Session bean [class a.b.ejb.EchoServiceBean with qualifiers [@Any @Default]; local interfaces are [EchoService]
getName(): a.b.ejb.EchoServiceBean
getSimpleName(): EchoServiceBean
getSuperclass(): class java.lang.Object
getPackage(): a.b.ejb
getAnnotations(): [@javax.ejb.Stateless(name=, description=, mappedName=)]

(55)
toString(): Managed Bean [class org.mybatis.cdi.CDIUtils$SerializableDefaultAnnotationLiteral] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
getName(): org.mybatis.cdi.CDIUtils$SerializableDefaultAnnotationLiteral
getSimpleName(): SerializableDefaultAnnotationLiteral
getSuperclass(): class javax.enterprise.util.AnnotationLiteral
getPackage(): org.mybatis.cdi
getAnnotations(): []


(56)
toString(): Managed Bean [class a.b.web.CdiServlet] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
getName(): a.b.web.CdiServlet
getSimpleName(): CdiServlet
getSuperclass(): class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
getPackage(): a.b.web
getAnnotations(): [@javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet(loadOnStartup=-1, initParams=[], urlPatterns=[], displayName=, largeIcon=, name=, asyncSupported=false, description=, smallIcon=, value=[/cdi])]

(58)
toString(): Producer Method [SqlSessionFactory] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @ApplicationScoped @Produces @SessionFactoryProvider public a.b.ejb.SessionFactoryProducerImpl.produce()]
getName(): a.b.ejb.SessionFactoryProducerImpl
getSimpleName(): SessionFactoryProducerImpl
getSuperclass(): class java.lang.Object
getPackage(): a.b.ejb
getAnnotations(): []

(70)
toString(): Managed Bean [class a.b.ejb.SessionFactoryProducerImpl] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
getName(): a.b.ejb.SessionFactoryProducerImpl
getSimpleName(): SessionFactoryProducerImpl
getSuperclass(): class java.lang.Object
getPackage(): a.b.ejb
getAnnotations(): []

72)
toString(): Managed Bean [class a.b.commons.domain.Configuration] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
getName(): a.b.commons.domain.Configuration
getSimpleName(): Configuration
getSuperclass(): class java.lang.Object
getPackage(): a.b.commons.domain
getAnnotations(): []
```

I can see that my `SessionFactoryProducerImpl` is injected either with or without @Stateless annotation (bean id 70). I also can see that SqlSessionFactory producer is injected as well, bean id 58.

But I still get `org.mybatis.cdi.MybatisCdiConfigurationException: There are no SqlSessionFactory producers properly configured` error when I call the `echo(...)` method of my EJB.

I guess that somehow MyBatis needs to use producer method from `a.b.ejb.SessionFactoryProducerImpl`. But how to tell it to mybatis-cdi?

Comment: First of all try to deploy the example App. It has been tested with many Application Servers and it has a sample EJB. Then just change mybatis-config_1.xml to use MANAGED transactions. The Session Factory Producer is not intended to be used directly but internally by mybatis-cdi.

Link to example app: https://github.com/mnesarco/mybatis-cdi-samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation does not tell to remove `@Stateless`, it just does not specify it is required because it describes general use case. Then try:

```
@Stateless
@Local(SessionFactoryProducer.class)
public class SessionFactoryProducerImpl implements SessionFactoryProducer {
    //@Override
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Produces
    @Named("fooManager")
    @SessionFactoryProvider
    public SqlSessionFactory produce() throws IOException {
       ...
    }
}
```

`@Local(SessionFactoryProducer.class)` and `implements SessionFactoryProducer` might even be not mandatory.

I suppose `@Stateless` turn the `SessionFactoryProducer` into an EJB that will then be available in the same context/scope and can be injected into another.

The `SessionFactoryProducer`is just required to be present. Afterwards this is CDI's job to invoke it when  it finds SqlSession or Mapper injection points.

This is pretty much what I have done, the session is managed by EJB. Of course provided mybatis-config.xml:

```
<environments default="development">
  <environment id="development">
    <transactionManager type="MANAGED">
    <dataSource type="JNDI">
```

Comment: You are correct. "@Local" and "implement" keywords are not necessary. As I can see "@Stateless" is not necessary as well. As you can see in UPDATE-2 the SqlSessionFactory is injected but still get error :(

Comment: my mybatis.xml is pretty much similar with yours

Comment: All the magic is that only annotations are required, CDI does all the work. I I think `@Stateless` is required anyway: even though SessionFactoryProducer is instantiated, it is somehow not reachable (different scope ... this what the error logs says) to be invoked and  EJB injected with SqlSession/Mapper, `@Stateless` turns it into an EJB, unlike when working with simple webapp (no EJB).

Comment: What kind of application server are you using?

Comment: I'm using Jboss EAP 6.3

Comment: It seems that this issue is related to appserver. It is a classpath issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154419/mybatis-cdi-class-loader-issue-in-case-of-ear