# MyBatis CDI class loader issue in case of EAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, mybatis, ear, ibatis

I have an EAR which at the moment contains only one WAR. My issue is if the *mybatis-....jar* files locate under *web-module.war\WEB-INF\lib* then everything works fine. BUT if I create a skinny war with maven and the two mybatis related jars locate under EAR/lib I get a "*There are no SqlSessionFactory producers properly configured.*" error.

I seems that it is a classpath related issue.

I am planning to add more WAR into my EAR and I would like to avoid the situation to put these two jars into each WARs.

Environment: Java 8, Payara Server 4.1.2.172

**This is the structure of my EAR, but it does not work**

```
EAR
  +-- lib
       + mybatis-3.4.4.jar
       + mybatis-cdi-1.0.0.jar

  +-- web-module.war
```

The web module contains a servlet with an injected EJB. This EJB uses myBatis mapper.

**Servlet**

```
@WebServlet("/echo")
public class EchoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private EchoService echoService;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        try (PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter()) {
            writer.println(echoService.echo("lorempisum"));
        }
    }
}
```

**EJB**

```
@Stateless
public class EchoBean implements EchoService {

    @Inject
    private AccountDao accountDao;

    @Override
    public String echo(String text) {
        List<String> emails = accountDao.findAll();
        return "Hello " + text + "! There are " + emails.size() + " emails in the DB.");
    }
}
```

**MyBatis mapper**

```
@Mapper
public interface AccountDao {
    @Select("SELECT email FROM dev.account")
    List<String> findAll();
}
```

**If I change the structure of my EAR then my project works fine.**

```
EAR
  +-- lib

  +-- web-module.war
       +-- WEB-INF
            +-- lib
                 +-- mybatis-3.4.4.jar
                 +-- mybatis-cdi-1.0.0.jar
```

---

I tried to add *MANIFEST.MF* file to *ear\web-module.war\META-INF* directory with the following content but it did not help:

```
Class-Path: lib/mybatis-3.4.4.jar lib/mybatis-cdi-1.0.0.jar
```

I also tried to add *glassfish-web.xml* file to *ear\web-module.war\WEB-INF* directory as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/bearq.html) but it did not help:

```
<glassfish-web-app>
    <class-loader delegate="true" extra-class-path="../lib/mybatis-3.4.4.jar:../lib/mybatis-cdi-1.0.0.jar"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Any idea how to solve this classpath issue?

Answer (score -1):

I don't remember exactly whether it was the reason why we eventually came to this but: having your EAR components unpacked (simple folders for wars and ejbs inside ear archive) could help.

Here is the config with Maven:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <applicationName>myApp</applicationName>
        <version>6</version>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <initializeInOrder>true</initializeInOrder>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>APP-INF/lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        <unpackTypes>war,ejb</unpackTypes>
        <modules>
            <ejbModule>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>myapp-ejb</artifactId>
                <bundleFileName>myapp-ejb.jar</bundleFileName>
            </ejbModule>
            <webModule>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>myapp-rest</artifactId>
                <contextRoot>/myapp</contextRoot>
                <bundleFileName>myapp.war</bundleFileName>
            </webModule>
        </modules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

**This is the solution:**

- to read: [mybatis-cdi issue tracker](https://github.com/mybatis/cdi/issues/61)
- to read: [payara app server issue tracker](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1688)
- src: [my mybatis-ee-demo application](https://github.com/zappee/mybatis-ee-demo)
- src: [my mybatis-web-demo application](https://github.com/zappee/mybatis-web-demo)